# How can I dynamically use GET in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, dynamic, get

So, I have the following PHP code.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ${'product' . $i . 'Id'} = ${'_GET["product' . $i . 'Id"]'};
}
```

I want the output to be something similar to this.

```
$product1Id = $_GET["product1Id"];
$product2Id = $_GET["product2Id"];
$product3Id = $_GET["product3Id"];
```

So that I can echo them later.

```
echo $product1Id;
echo $product2Id;
echo $product3Id;
```

Comment: Just use the array as an array.... it's far easier to work with than a host of individual variables.... and if you use it as an array  in your URL, it's easier still.... numbered variable names like this are almost inevitably a sign of bad design

Comment: @Joshua see this; https://3v4l.org/ulAEV

Comment: @Joshua - first off, learn to recognise the difference between criticism and critique

Comment: Then, rather than creating a url that looks like `http://www.examplesite.org/products.php?product1Id=ABC&product2Id=DEF&product3Id=GHI` where every product id is individually numbered, create a url like `http://www.examplesite.org/products.php?productIds[]=ABC&productIds[]=DEF&productIds[]=GHI`.... then you can reference it using `$_GET['productIds']` in your PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, your `for` loop should be like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ${'product' . $i . 'Id'} = $_GET['product' . $i . 'Id'];
}
```

**Or,** instead of this `for` loop you can simply do `extract($_GET);`. This will directly give you the required variables and the associated values. Reference: **http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php**

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to this type of code and you helped me a lot.

Comment: @Joshua Glad I could help. :-) I've added an additional method to achieve the exact same result, you may also want to look at that as well.

Comment: There is a warning NOT to use it for `$_GET` on the link you provided. `Warning

Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).
`

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
${'product' . $i . 'Id'} = $_GET["product{$i}Id"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you <3.
For getting out puts like this($product1Id = $_GET["product1Id"]) using for , you can make a for like this !
you can make an array that each elements of that array contains one of the get values you get !I think This is better than making lots of variables ! Try to put your values in an array like the code below !
The first step is to make an array with 0 elements.

```
$array_get_values = new array();
```

now its time to make the for , and put values in it.

```
for($i=1 ; $i =< 3;$i++)
{
 $array_get_values[] = $_GET["product".$i."Id"];
}
```

and now you have all your values in array and you can call them by their address.

```
Note : $array_get_values[] => this piece of code , adds new element to our array
```

i hope i've helped you ! Good luck bro

Comment: You cannot instantiate array in php. array() is not a class neither does it exist.

Comment: Why are you taking values from one array and place them in another array? How is that going to help?

Comment: @Andreas He wanted to Save Values , from get method , and he was creating variable for all of Get values , if you want to create variables manualy , you may need to create 20 variables , so this makes your code huge with lots of lines ! but if you save them into an array , it reduces your code , and it helps you when you have alot of get values ! or unknown values !

Comment: @Akintunde one of the ways of creating an array with unknown elements , is to make them like the way i said ! , you can do that ! there are several ways ! the simplest , was this ! good luck <3

Comment: $_GET is an array. All that code you have there is useless because all you do is move values from one array to another. From an array with named keys (that is easy to use) to an array with keys 0,1,2 and so on. Array_values can remove they named keys. See here a oneliner would do the same as your code https://3v4l.org/qaogK . But either way OP wanted variables, not an array. Yes arrays are smarter but it's not our code.

Answer (score 0):

Use extract to make the array $_GET individual variables.

```
extract($_GET);

Echo $product1Id . $product2Id . $product3Id;
```

Since I can't make this "happen" on a online PHP tester I created an array just like your GET array.
See the demo here.
https://3v4l.org/RqjRd